# Why can't my main class identify my methods?

Tags: java

The question states:

Create a class  Rectangle with double  attributes length and width. The default constructor  should set these attributes to 
 1. Provide methods  that calculate the rectangle's perimeter and area, as well as accessors and mutators for both data fields. The mutator methods  for length and width should verify that the number being passed in is larger  than 0.0 and less than  20.0 -- if it doesn't fit those criteria, the value  of the field should not be changed.

Write a Driver class  in the same file to test your Rectangle class . It should prompt the user to enter a length and width of a rectangle, and then print out the area and perimeter of the rectangle. (Use the mutators to set the length and width of the rectangle, not the constructor .)

This is the sample run: [Sample run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St49d.png)

And this is the code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter length of rectangle:");
    double height = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter width of rectangle:");
    double width = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("Area: %f, Perimeter: %f", getArea(), getPerimeter());

}

public static class Rectangle {
private double height;
private double width;

public Rectangle(double wid, double high) {
    height = high;
    width = wid;
} 

public void setHeight(double high) {
    width = wid > 0.0 && wid < 20.0 ? wid : 0;
}

public void setWidth(double wid){
    width = wid > 0.0 && wid < 20.0 ? wid : 0;
}

public double getArea() {
    return height*width;
}

public double getPerimeter() {
    return 2*(height + width);
}
}
}
```

I appreciate any help!
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cEf4.png)

Comment: `height = high > 0.0 && high < 20.0;` and `width = wid > 0.0 && wid < 20.0;` are supposed to do what?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch obviously, anything beyond the boundary(0, 20) will be ignored.

Comment: @JerryChin Ternaries were added in edits... my comment preserves the original state of the question. Which is what now?

Comment: @JerryChin I meant for those to validate that the number read is is larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0

Answer (score 1):

That's because those methods don't belong to Driver class. They belong to Rectangle. Instantiate your Rectangle first, then use its methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter length of rectangle:");
    double height = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter width of rectangle:");
    double width = input.nextDouble();

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(width, height);

    System.out.printf("Area: %f, Perimeter: %f", r.getArea(), r.getPerimeter());

}
```

Also, your setters are totally mixed up.

```
    public Rectangle(double wid, double high) {
        // Your constructor didn't use validation
        setWidth(wid);
        setHeight(high);
    }

    public void setHeight(double high) {
       // If you really want to have validation in your setter, that's the syntax, yours doesn't compile
        height = high > 0.0 && high < 20.0 ? high : 0;
    }

    public void setWidth(double wid){
        width = wid > 0.0 && wid < 20.0 ? wid : 0;
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense however when I add that I get an error that states: "No enclosing instance of type Driver is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Driver (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Driver)."

Comment: Either make your Rectangle static class, or, much better, extract it to a separate file.

Comment: I ended up making Rectangle a static class because thats what the instructions say. However, I think I have an error in my calculations  for the actual area and perimeter but I can't seem to figure it out:/

Comment: Ok based on you recommendations, I am getting the correct numbers when calculated by hand. However, the answer provided online says that the area=6.8 and the perimeter=15.6 if the user enters 23.4 for the length and 6.8 for the width. I know that this is wrong but do u have any idea as to how they derived this?

Comment: If only the width is 6.8, how the whole area can be 6.8? You got your numbers mixed up now.

Comment: Yea I figured the website mixed up their numbers haha but does my code fit the requirements based on the instructions?

Comment: I believe I missed something from the instructions regarding the default constructors. Should I create a separate one and initialize the values to 1? Also let me know if I miss anything:) thanks again for the help

Comment: I don't know what your instructions are. From the code perspective, if you apply my suggestions, your code should be fine.

Comment: I wasn't sure what these meant: The default constructor should set these attributes to 1 and Use the mutators to set the length and width of the rectangle, not the constructor

Answer (score 0):

To call a method of a class you should have an instance of that class. In this case you are trying to access the methods of the `Rectangle` class in the the Class `Driver` which is not possible. So you have to create an instance the of the `Rectangle` class as

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
```

and then you can access the methods of this instance as:

```
rect.getArea(); 
...
```

I recommend to read the Java basics, for example at [Java Tutorial site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

I commented all the relevant parts so that you can see why your code is not working:

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter length of rectangle:");
    double height = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter width of rectangle:");
    double width = input.nextDouble();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(); // Create instance of Rectangle
    rect.setHeight(height); // use mutators to set the values
    rect.setWidth(width);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.0#");
    System.out.printf("Area: %s, Perimeter: %s", df.format(rect.getArea()), df.format(rect.getPerimeter()));

}

static class Rectangle {
    private double height;
    private double width;

    // default constructor(=constrcutor without parameter) should set dimensions to 1
    public Rectangle() {
        height = 1.0;
        width = 1.0;
    }

    // Define mutators
    public void setHeight(double height) {
        if (height > 0.0 && height < 20.0) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        if (width > 0.0 && width < 20.0) {
            this.width = width;
        }
    }


    // Define accessors
    double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return height * width;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (height + width);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: With your code the decimals in the output would display for example area=7.450000 and perimeter=16.900000 How would I remove the trailing zeros and keep 7.45 and 16.9?

Comment: Ive tried that and it solves rounding the 7.45 but it still leaves a 0 after 16.9. I there a way to get rid trailing zeros without knowing how many decimal places a number greater than zero will end? For example, if I ended up with a number 7.342000 and 5.345670000 then I wound want to round that to 7.342 and 5.34567.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether it is 16.9 or 16.90? Anyway, I don't know any standard way to do it; but I could program myself if it is necessary.

Comment: Not to me but it does for the online platform for which i have to submit it unfortunately:( I tried using `%.1f` and for example it would give me an OK for the 16.9 but it wont let me submit because the 7.45 is rounded to 7.5.

Comment: I think it is possible using `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: I haven't heard about that yet would u mind editing it into the code? Im wondering if its like String.format or is that a different method?

Comment: I modified the code. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I added an error link in my first post showing what it states after the decimal format. Unfortunately yes there's still an error haha but don't worry I'm starting to think that maybe its just the online platform I'm using:(

Comment: modified again (use `0` instead of `#`) => `0` means there must be a digit even if it is zero; `#` means truncate trailing zero.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I will definitely need to learn decimal formatting